# can the given code be optimized, i have tried doing it by referring different sites but it always shows me error

Tags: python, arrays, list

Can the below code be further optimised?

```
r, c = map(int, input().split())

arr = []
for j in range(r):
    s = list(map(int, input().split()))
    arr.append(s)

print(arr)
```

eg:

3 3

1 2 3

1 2 3

7 8 9

o/p: [[1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3], [7, 8, 9]]

Comment: That depends on what you mean with "optimised". There's no error handling and the variable names are not good.

Comment: If your code runs correctly and you just want to improve it, you should ask on the [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/) tackexchange site instead :D

Answer (score 0):

```
print([list(map(int, input().split())) for j in range(int(input()))])
```

Comment: While this code may resolve the OP's issue, it is best to include an explanation as to how your code addresses the OP's issue. In this way, future visitors can learn from your post, and apply it to their own code. SO is not a coding service, but a resource for knowledge. Also, high quality, complete answers are more likely to be upvoted. These features, along with the requirement that all posts are self-contained, are some of the strengths of SO as a platform, that differentiates it from forums. You can edit to add additional info &/or to supplement your explanations with source documentation.